# how to force mdadm to sync to device after raid6 repair and how to get number of errors?

Tags: sync, mdadm, raid6

## The Question

After a component device suffered unexpected bit-flip, and after a raid6 `repair` was successfully performed on the raid device, how to force mdadm to sync the changes from buffer(?) back onto the component device?

And how to monitor when such a repair happens?

## The Setup

For testing purposes I made the following setup (using bash on a debian jessie):

```
sudo -i
mkdir testbed
cd testbed
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    dd if=/dev/zero of=disk$i bs=1M count=4
    losetup loop$i disk$i
done
mdadm --create /dev/md/test --level=6 --raid-devices=4 /dev/loop{1,2,3,4}
mkfs.vfat /dev/md/test # Note: has easier hexdump than ext
mkdir mounted
mount /dev/md/test mounted
echo "Hello World!" > mounted/message
```

## The unexpected bit-flip

The test scenario assumes that some bit(s) on one of the component devices change while the raid device is not running.

```
umount mounted
mdadm --stop /dev/md/test
# Note: does show 'H' from 'Hello World!' at position 0x00107a00
hexdump -C /dev/loop1
# manipulate some bits in first component device at 0x00107a00
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 seek=1079808 of=/dev/loop1
# Note: now changed to ".ello World!" at position 0x00107a00
hexdump -C /dev/loop1
```

## The repair

Now start the raid device again, and try to persuade mdadm to detect and repair the faulty bits on the component device.

#### assembling and mounting

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md/test /dev/loop{1,2,3,4}
mount /dev/md/test mounted
# dmesg does not show error
# hexdump still shows faulty bits
```

this is expected.

#### reading the faulty sectors

```
cat mounted/message # always reads the non-faulty message
# nothing in dmesg
# no raid6 related message in /var/log/syslog
# /sys/block/md127/md/mismatch_cnt == 0
# hexdump still shows faulty bits
```

by now, mdadm should have detected the mismatching checksum, and by majority vote determined that /dev/loop1 is faulty. But there is no warning or error count about this anywhere.

#### initiate repair

```
echo repair > /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action
sync # should be completely unrelated for this question
# dmesg reports successful resync
# /var/log/syslog replicates the dmesg messages
# hexdump -C /dev/loop1 still shows faulty bits as 0x00107a00
```

mdadm sure must have noticed the faulty bits by now, but for some reason did not write the repaired chunk back to disk.

#### need to stop raid device

it seems neccessary to stop the raid device (thus making the file system temporarily unavailable!) in order to force sync of repaired chunk.

```
umount mounted
mdadm --stop /dev/md/test
```

finally, hexdump finally shows correct 'H' again.
but no indication of faulty chunk in dmesg or syslog nor mismatch_cnt.